# SwiftUI NavigationLink not behaving the same way as the old NavigationButton

Tags: swift, swiftui, xcode11

in Xcode 11 beta 3, `NavigationButton` was renamed to `NavigationLink`

So I have made the change to my project but now the app is behaving completely differently. You cannot click on the Images anymore, but you can click on the space behind them, but if you do that, it opens all the detail views and cycles between them. I made a Demo here: [Youtube](https://youtu.be/-uXd2zBUmds)

There was another issue but it was fixed by replacing `ScrollView(showsHorizontalIndicator: false)` with `ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false)`.

[SourceCode -Github](https://github.com/MrBenFTW/CoffeeDBApp)

Comment: I added the link to the Git repo since SwiftUI uses multiple files and combines it into 1 UI

Comment: And yes, Changing `NavigationButton` to `NavigationLink` broke it.